# How to install b43-lpphy-installer for Debian?

Tags: linux, debian, wifi

I have installed Debian and its version is Linux version 3.16.0-4-amd64

Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)

How do I install b43-lpphy-installer for this version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

b43-lpphy-installer is the name of the package for Ubuntu, not for Debian.

You install it with the command in jessie (Debian 8):

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

By the kernel version, you seem to be using Debian 8.

To find out details about debian packages, you can search packages by name or their files at:

https://packages.debian.org/

For instance, the package in question can be consulted here:

https://packages.debian.org/jessie/firmware-b43-installer

From our dialogue, I have seen you still have no apt sources configured.

To be able to install the packages, and also download security updates from the Internet, you would better comment out the line from /etc/apt/sources.list to install from CD/DVD:

```
#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8 _Jessie_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20150908-22:02]/ jessie main
```

and add this two lines, one to install the official packages, and another to install the updates:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib  non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
```

After inserting this lines, you do an

```
sudo apt-get install update
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install upgrade
```

To install the latest security upgrades. You might want to do this regularly.

And afterwards, before installing any package, you do before

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And lastly

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Comment: I am getting: Unable to locate package firmware-b43-installer. My network controller is 'BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY'

Comment: It is in the contrib repo...show me please your /etc/apt/sources.list, we have to add the contrib to it

Comment: Please check here: http://pastebin.com/NC1hpqK9

Comment: Checked, you still have it configure for the DVD/CD. Already updated the instructions.

Comment: thanks a lot. Wifi is working after following the instructions and reboot

Comment: Excellent! Enjoy your new Debian. We are here to help.